# Android Sprite

Tags: веб-программирование, android, спрайт

Добрый день.
Мне нужно отобразить в ListView текст и изображения с сайта. Текст я получаю распарсивая html, а все изображения получаю как спрайт. Получается я должен основываясь на CSS в приложении разрезать этот спрайт? Т.е. парсить еще и CSS? Может есть вариант легче?
Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Что-то я не до конца понял, причем тут CSS ? Вам нужно использовать вот эту библиотеку для скачивания картинок http://nostra13android.blogspot.ru/2012/03/4-universal-image-loader-part-1.html и с её помощью уже вставлять в свой листвью картинки

Comment: Спасибо. Я думал CSS нужен был чтобы понять какую картинку из спрайта какому тексту сопоставить.

Answer (score 1):

То есть у вас все используемые изображения склеены в единый спрайт, верно я вас понимаю?

В таком случае - да, единственный вариант - программно разбирать CSS (background, background-image, background-position, background-position-x, background-position-y и т.д.), и, следуя этим правилам, разрезать общий спрайт на отдельные изображения.